# Average time to first repair for various computer manufacturers

Tags: warranty

I remember reading an article on LifeHacker once which compared PC manufacturers based on the average time their computer lasted before requiring a repair.

Where could I find such statistics today? (I'm wondering if the extended warranty is worth buying for my new computer).

Thanks.